# Scrollbar not appearing when draggable bootsrap modal dialog is dragged to left most or top most in a browser window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-draggable

[Scroll bar appearing when bootstrap modal dialog moved to right most or to bottom in browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfuPL.png)

[Scroll bar not appearing when bootstrap modal dialog moved to left most or top most in browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEiq1.png)

Comment: I've tried overflow: auto which didn't work too

Comment: Only a guess, but set your max-width and max-height on body (or most outer `div`).  It looks like it is increasing and causing the whole page to scroll when modal is "out of bounds".

Comment: @user2796515 setting max width and height will affect the view when monitor sizes are different. Yes it enables scroll only when modal is out of bounds on right most and bottom. i want it on all sides.